# AlertDialog and some views clickables

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

i am writing a game code and i want make a mini tutorial at the start of the game to learn players how to play!

In some games i saw a good thing and i want do the same: an `AlertDialog` is over the `activity` but some `view`s are not dark like the rest of the windows...so the users reading the `alertdialog` and showing `view`s highlighted understand that they have to click on these views.

I tried use `alertdialog` but probably i did some mistake!

Can someone help me to understand if can i use `alertdialog` to do that things?if it is possible how can i do that?
Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your own XML Layout to the dialog and FULLY CUSTOMIZE IT... Inside the XML file you can put whatever you want and colors etc.